# TIFF image: empty colormap and not plotted - Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, tiff

I'm trying to geo-reference and plot a TIF image in MATLAB. I have the .tif image (map Width: 1440, Height: 400) and its corresponding coordinate extent .tfw file. Upon opening the files as:

```
[X, cmap] = imread('image.tif');
R_orig = worldfileread('image.tfw','planar',size(X));
```

I get an empty colormap and a black image when I plot it:

```
mapshow(X,cmap,R_orig)
```

Using '`imagesc(X)`' does show the map correctly, but without the coordinates of course. This is the figure information:

```
BitDepth: 16
ColorType: 'grayscale'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'BlackIsZero'
PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
MaxSampleValue: 65535
MinSampleValue: 0
```

Any help please?

**UPDATE**:
I was able to circumvent the issue with the following code. Maybe there's a better solution?

```
[X, ~] = imread(['image.tif']);
R_orig = worldfileread(['image.tfw'],'planar',size(X));
cmap = colormap(jet);
Xdoub = double(X) + 1;
mapshow(Xdoub,cmap,R_orig);
```

Comment: Is this specific to that image or any image will reproduce it? If its image specific, put the image

Comment: Any TIF image should work

Comment: `mapshow(X,cmap,R_orig)` this is wrong. Read the docs

Comment: hi @AnderBiguri , it actually plots the map though, but i'm ultimately interested in having a cmap for the TIFF not the converted image

Comment: Even if it plots the map, it s wrong. Please read the documentation

Comment: Put mapshow aside for a moment please. I need the colormap... a frequency table of the attributes of the TIF file

Comment: `colormap(cmap)`?

Comment: right, that'd work in usual circumstances, but I get an empty cmap... the TIF has uint16 :/

Comment: So, you have an image without a colormap, and you want to apply its colormap to something? That makes no sense. if the TIF is uin16, grayscale, then it has no colomap